# How to optimize this Playfair encryption?

Tags: c#, cryptography

For the implementation of the Playfair encryption I needed a custom struct called Cell. This is because I not only need an array of characters I also want to get Elements in a matrix based on their "cartesian" position.

```
public struct Cell 
    {
        public char character;
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public Cell(char _character,int _X, int _Y) 
        {
            this.character = _character;
            this.X = _X;
            this.Y = _Y;
        }
    }
```

Then I implement the method which calculates the cipher.

```
public static string PlayfairCipher(string keyWord,string plainText)
{

    //Define alphabet
    //There is no J in the alphabet instead I is used
    char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

    #region Adjust Key
    keyWord = keyWord.Trim();
    keyWord = keyWord.Replace(" ", "");
    keyWord = keyWord.Replace("J", "I");
    keyWord = keyWord.ToUpper();

    StringBuilder keyString = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(char c in keyWord)
    {
        if(!keyString.ToString().Contains(c))
        {
            keyString.Append(c);
            alphabet = alphabet.Where(val => val != c).ToArray();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Adjust plain text
    plainText = plainText.Trim();
    plainText = plainText.Replace(" ", "");
    plainText = plainText.Replace("J", "I");
    plainText = plainText.ToUpper();

    //If the Length of the plain text is odd add X
    if((plainText.Length % 2 > 0))
    {
        plainText += "X";
    }

    List<string> plainTextEdited = new List<string>();

    //Split plain text into pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length;i += 2)
    {
        //If a pair of chars contains the same letters replace one of them with X
        if (plainText[i].ToString() == plainText[i + 1].ToString())
        {
            plainTextEdited.Add(plainText[i].ToString() + 'X');
        }
        else {
            plainTextEdited.Add(plainText[i].ToString() + plainText[i + 1].ToString());
        }


    }
    #endregion

    #region Create 5 x 5 matrix

    List<Cell> matrix = new List<Cell>();
    int keyIDCounter = 0;
    int alphabetIDCounter = 0;
    //Fill the matrix. First with the key characters then with the alphabet
    for (int x = 0; x < 5;x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            if (keyIDCounter < keyString.Length)
            {

                Cell cell = new Cell(keyString[keyIDCounter],x,y);
                matrix.Add(cell);
                keyIDCounter++;
            }
            else {
                Cell cell = new Cell(alphabet[alphabetIDCounter], x, y);
                matrix.Add(cell);
                alphabetIDCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region Write cipher

    StringBuilder cipher = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(string pair in plainTextEdited)
    {

        int indexA = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.character == pair[0]);
        Cell a = matrix[indexA];

        int indexB = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.character == pair[1]);
        Cell b = matrix[indexB];

        //Write cipher
        if (a.X == b.X)
        {
            cipher.Append(matrix[matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == (a.X + 1)%5 && c.Y == a.Y)].character);
            cipher.Append(matrix[matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == (b.X + 1)%5 && c.Y == b.Y)].character);
        }
        else if(a.Y == b.Y)
        {
            cipher.Append(matrix[matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == a.X && c.Y == (a.Y + 1) % 5)].character);
            cipher.Append(matrix[matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == b.X % 5 && c.Y == (b.Y + 1) % 5)].character);
        }else
        {
            cipher.Append(matrix[matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == a.X && c.Y == b.Y)].character);
            cipher.Append(matrix[matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == b.X % 5 && c.Y == a.Y)].character);
        }

    }
    #endregion

    return cipher.ToString();

}
```

Should I split this into more separate methods? Do I really need the Cell struct or is there another way to get an element's coordinates? Also how is the overall implementation and code readability? What should I improve regarding future implementations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `Cell` struct should be immutable - you can achieve that by making all the fields `readonly`.
2. In `Cell` `character` should be `PascalCase`.
3. You repeat the code for trimming and replacing characters for they key and plain text. This should be moved into a method.
4. There is some convoluted code which iterates of the `keyWord` and adds stuff to a `keyString`. If I read it correctly then what this is doing is: Build a list of all unique characters and remove those from the alphabet. LINQ is perfect for doing that in a concise way:

   ```
   var uniqueKeyChars = keyWord.Distinct().ToList();
   alphabet = alphabet.Except(uniqueKeyChars).ToArray();
   ```
5. I would consider moving the whole pad-to-even-length and then split into pairs business into a separate methods as well. Also using a `Tuple` to represent pairs of characters seems to be more appropriate.

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<Tuple<char, char>> GetPairs(this IEnumerable<char> input)
   {
       while (input.Any())
       {
           var pair = input.Take(2);
           char first = pair.First();
           char second = pair.Skip(1).Any() ? pair.Last() : 'X';
           yield return Tuple.Create(first, second);
           input = input.Skip(2);
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   var plainTextPairs = plainText.GetPairs();
   ```
6. If you have followed the suggestions above you will now have a `uniqueKeyChars` array as well as the `alphabet` with the `uniqueKeyChars` removed. This should make building the matrix easier:

   ```
   var cellAlphabet = new Queue<char>(uniqueKeyChars.Concat(alphabet));
   for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
   {
       for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
       {
           var cell = new Cell(cellAlphabet(cellAlphabet.Dequeue()), x, y);
           matrix.Add(cell);
       }
   }
   ```
7. When creating the cipher if you split the index finding from the appending then the code becomes slightly more readable (below assuming you use the extension method shown above):

   ```
   foreach(string pair in plainTextPairs)
   {
       int indexA = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.character == pair.Item1);
       Cell a = matrix[indexA];

       int indexB = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.character == pair.Item2);
       Cell b = matrix[indexB];

       int cipherCellIndexA;
       int cipherCellIndexB;

       //Write cipher
       if (a.X == b.X)
       {
           cipherCellIndexA = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == (a.X + 1) % 5 && c.Y == a.Y);
           cipherCellIndexB = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == (b.X + 1)%5 && c.Y == b.Y);
       }
       else if(a.Y == b.Y)
       {
           cipherCellIndexA = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == a.X && c.Y == (a.Y + 1) % 5);
           cipherCellIndexB = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == b.X % 5 && c.Y == (b.Y + 1) % 5);
       }else
       {
           cipherCellIndexA = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == a.X && c.Y == b.Y);
           cipherCellIndexB = matrix.FindIndex(c => c.X == b.X % 5 && c.Y == a.Y);
       }

       cipher.Append(matrix[cipherCellIndexA].Character);
       cipher.Append(matrix[cipherCellIndexB].Character);
   }
   ```

   Of course of you would make your matrix an actual 2d array then you could skip the whole `FindIndex` shebang and just pick the cell by the index which should speed up things a bit.